# Defining a function from two columns in Pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a value, my first column, based on the units which is a second column, I have tried the following:

```
def my_conversion():
    for x in df['unit']:
        if x == 'b1':
            return(df['value'] * 0.125)
        elif x == 'b2':
            return(df['value'] * 0.25)
        elif x == 'b3':
            return(df['value'] * 0.00781)
        elif x == 'b4':
            return(df['value'] / 3785411800000)
        else:
            return(df['value'])
```

Then I am using apply to create a new column:

```
df['value_converted'] = df['value'].apply(my_conversion)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
my_conversion() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: you have `x=='b3'`  twice in your `elif` statements, doing two different things to `df['value']`

Comment: Can you please update the question with full sample code, so that we can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I have updated the question. Thank you

Comment: `apply` passes an argument (the row) to it, so you have to allow for that in your definition. I would be looking to broadcast iterating over the unique units that you want to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the values in `df['unit']` to the numerical value you have in your if-statements, by using `.map()`. You can then multiply these mapped values with `df['value']` in an element-wise manner:

```
m = {'b1' : .125, 'b2' : .25, 'b3':  0.00781, 'b4': 1./3785411800000}
df['value_converted'] = df['unit'].map(m).fillna(1) * df['value']
```

Equivalent, but a bit more elaborate, lengthy and explicit would be:

```
mapping_dictionary = {'b1': .125, 
                      'b2': .250, 
                      'b3': .00781, 
                      'b4': 1./37854118}

df['mapped_values'] = df['unit'].map(mapping_dictionary).fillna(1)
df['value_converted'] = df['mapped_values'] * df['value']
```

I know, it does not answer the question, but it solves your problem.

Comment: I would suggest taking care to ensure you've answered the question completely... that means doing better than an 80% right answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`apply` method runs through all rows by default so you don't have to have a loop inside your function. It should look like this:

```
def my_conversion(row):
    if row['unit']=='b1':
        return(row['value']*0.125)
    elif row['unit']=='b2':
        return(row['value']*0.25)
    elif row['unit']=='b3':
        return(row['value']*0.00781)
    elif row['unit']=='b4':
        return(row['value']/3785411800000)
    else:
        return(row['value'])
```

And you need to invoke it for whole df:

```
df['value_converted'] = df.apply(my_conversion, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have tested all three methods and all of them work fine. Many thanks for your answers

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to show you why your initial approach didn't work. Also this solution doesn't require creating temporary columns.

Answer (score 0):

This site shows several different ways to do exactly what you are asking, with varying levels of speed.

https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/

Here's a quick example that I tested and works.

```
def apply_tariff_isin(df):
    b1 = df.unit.isin(['b1'])
    b2 = df.unit.isin(['b2'])
    b3 = df.unit.isin(['b3'])
    b4 = df.unit.isin(['b4'])


    df.loc[b1, 'new_value'] = df.loc[b1, 'value'] * .125
    df.loc[b2,'new_value'] = df.loc[b2, 'value'] * .25
    df.loc[b3,'new_value'] = df.loc[b3, 'value'] * .00781
    df.loc[b4,'new_value'] = df.loc[b4, 'value'] / 3785411800000
```